# How do I create a CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR of unknown size?

Tags: winapi, drag-and-drop

I have an [email client](http://memecode.com/scribe.php) that allows the user to export a folder of email as a MBOX file. The UX is that they drag the folder from inside the application to an explorer folder (e.g. the Desktop) and a file copy commences via the application adding CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR and CFSTR_FILECONTENTS to the data object being dropped. The issue arises when working out how to specify the size of the "file". Because internally I store the email in a database and it takes quite a while to fully encode the output MBOX, especially if the folder has many emails. Until that encoding is complete I don't have an exact size... just an estimate.

Currently I return an IStream pointer to windows, and over-specify the size in the file descriptor (estimate * 3 or something). Then when I hit the end of my data I return a IStream::Read length less then the input buffer size. Which causes Windows to give up on the copy. In Windows 7 it leaves the "partial" file there in the destination folder which is perfect, but in XP it fails the copy completely, leaving nothing in the destination folder. Other versions may exhibit different behaviour.

Is there a way of dropping a file of unknown size onto explorer that has to be generated by the source application?

Alternatively can I just get the destination folder path and do all the copy progress + output internally to my application? This would be great, I have all the code to do it already. Problem is I'm not the process accepting the drop.

Bonus round: This also needs to work on Linux/GTK and Mac/Carbon so any pointers there would be helpful too.

Comment: Does your IStream implement Seek and Stat methods?

Comment: There is a token Stat method but because I don't know the size I don't have a value to stick in the size field. For seek, yes... that is there too.

Comment: My recommendation - 1) remove FD_FILESIZE flag, 2) do not implement Seek (should return E_NOTIMPL), 3) Stat.FileSize = -1

Comment: @denis I've tried that and explorer (my drop target) aborts the copy altogether.

Comment: Did you implement all 3 points (I mean in your code FD_FILESIZE flag must be deleted **AND** Seek must return E_NOTIMPL **AND** Stat must return FileSize equal to -1)? In my NSE it works. Windows internal Zip NSE does the same.

Comment: Sorry my seek function IS implemented... I'll drop that and see what happens.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov after getting all the pieces in place it DOES work. No progress obviously because the total size is not known, but a dialog appears and all the data is written to the destination. If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll mark it answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Explorer use three methods to detect size of stream (in order of priority):

1. nFileSizeHigh/Low fields of FILEDESCRIPTOR structure if FD_FILESIZE flags is present.
2. Calling IStream.Seek(0, STREAM_SEEK_END, FileSize).
3. Calling IStream.Stat. cbSize field of STATSTG structure is used as MAX file size only.

To pass to Explorer a file with unknown size it is necessary:

1. Remove FD_FILESIZE flags from FILEDESCRIPTOR structure.
2. IStream.Seek must not be implemented (must return E_NOTIMPL).
3. IStream.Stat must set cbSize field to -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way of dropping a file of unknown size onto explorer that has to be generated by the source application?

When providing `CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR`, you don't have to provide a file size at all if you don't know it ahead of time.  The `FD_FILESIZE` flag in the `FILEDESCRIPTOR::dwFlags` field is optional.  Provide an exact size only if you know it, otherwise don't provide a size at all, not even an estimate.  The copy will still proceed, but the target won't know the final size until `IStream::Read()` returns `S_FALSE` to indicate the end of the stream has been reached.

> Alternatively can I just get the destination folder path and do all the copy progress + output internally to my application?

A drop operation does not provide any information about the target at all.  And for good reason - the source doesn't *need* to know.  A drop target does not need to know where the source data is coming from, only how to access it.  The drag source does not need to know how the drop target will use the data, only how to provide the data to it.

Think of what happens if you drop a file (virtual or otherwise) onto an Explorer folder that is implemented as a Shell Namespace Extension that saves the file to another database, or uploads it to a remote server.  The filesystem is not involved, so you wouldn't be able to manually copy your data to the target even if you wanted to.  Only the target knows how its data is stored.

That being said, the only way I know to get the path of a filesystem folder being dropped into is to drag&drop a dummy file, and then monitor the filesystem for where the drop target creates/copies the file to.  Then you can replace the dummy file with your real file.  But this is not very reliable, and not very friendly to the target.

Comment: So I'm trying out your idea of not filling in the size in the file descriptor and what happens in practice (at least on Win7) is that the drag destination starts calling my IStream::Stat function, whereas it wasn't before. So it's going to ask for the exact size at some point, and won't continue until it gets it. I'm currently investigating what happens when I fill out everything I know in the ::Stat function but still leave the size unset.

Comment: AFAIK, `IStream::Stat()` does not provide a way to omit the size.

Comment: Yeah if I leave the STATSTG::size element as '0' the destination creates a zero length file, doesn't even call my ::Read function. So back to square one.

Comment: If possible, I would try adding a column in the DB to store the MBOX-encoded size of each email when it is added to the DB, and then sum those values together when calculating the `FILEDESCRIPTOR` file size.

Comment: Unless I can coerce one of the other clipboard formats into working... maybe CFSTR_INETURL? I think the best option is to give up and turn it into a push operation from inside the application. Right click on the folder -> "export MBOX" -> select folder dialog -> progress bar. But it's so clunky compared to d'n'd :(

Comment: Yes summing sizes would work. However at this point where the app is in use by 'n' users around the world and I would have to retrofit the functionality onto existing installs. And the calculation of these export sizes for existing email would have to be a background task on literally millions of email already stored in user's folders.